# Keras 2 similar dataset : 1 works other raises valueError

Tags: python, deep-learning, keras

I'm learning deep learning and trying to write some models. But I've stucked at data set. When I use ready code and data-set from github it works normally, but when I try my data set with same code it doesn't work. However , both datasets have same type and shape:

working dataset:

```
Shape of train:  (5000, 32, 32, 3)
Type of train:  <class 'numpy.ndarray'>
Shape of train labels:  (5000,)
Shape of valid:  (500, 32, 32, 3)
Shape of valid labels:  (500,)
```

my data-set:

```
Shape of train:  (31368, 32, 32, 3)
Type of train:  <class 'numpy.ndarray'>
Shape of train labels:  (31368,)
Shape of valid:  (7841, 32, 32, 3)
Shape of valid labels:  (7841, 32, 32, 3)
Shape of train_pixels[0]:  (32, 32, 3)
```

Error I got:

> ValueError: Error when checking model input: the list of Numpy arrays
>   that you are passing to your model is not the size the model expected.
>   Expected to see 1 arrays but instead got the following list of 7841
>   arrays: [array([[[186, 182, 255],
>           [179, 177, 255],
>           [163, 161, 244],...

There is one similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41248677/keras-array-input-error) I have found here but I couldn't use it, I got other errors. [This](https://github.com/fchollet/keras/issues/4002) solution doesn't work too.

Comment: Can you please post the function call you do that results in the error?

Comment: model.fit(train_pixels, train_labels, batch_size=batch_size, epochs=epoch, validation_data=(validation_pixels, validation_labels), shuffle=True)

Comment: I think I've solved the issue, I changed **(validation_pixels, validation_labels)** to **(np.array(validation_pixels), np.array(validation_labels))** and training started